# How to trigger Jenkins job by using Octopus deploy with powershell?

Tags: powershell, authentication, jenkins, http-status-code-403, octopus-deploy

I have a Jenkins Job, and that needs to get triggered by Octopus deploy. For that I have used the step template - **Jenkins -Queue Job** from Octopus library Installed Community Step Templates.

In the existing powershell script of the template, I have updated my parameters to run the Jenkins job. And finally during execution, I am facing the below error:

```
Exception in jenkins job: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
The remote script failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried the ways to authenticate Octopus with Jenkins, and still couldn't find a way. Can someone provide inputs with this ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue just now. I ended up just copying their template and making changes. The issue is related to not keeping the session cookie across requests. Note: I had to move their authentication code out of the function because the session variable data would not work for some reason.

```
$jenkinsServer = $OctopusParameters['jqj_JenkinsServer'] 
$jenkinsUserName = $OctopusParameters['jqj_JenkinsUserName']
$jenkinsUserPassword = $OctopusParameters['jqj_JenkinsUserPasword']
$jobURL = $jenkinsServer + $OctopusParameters['jqj_JobUrl']
$failBuild = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($OctopusParameters['jqj_FailBuild'])
$jobTimeout = $OctopusParameters['jqj_JobTimeout']
$buildParam = $OctopusParameters['jqj_BuildParam']
$checkIntervals = $OctopusParameters['jqj_checkInterval']

$jobUrlWithParams = "$jobURL$buildParam"

Write-Host "job url: " $jobUrlWithParams 

try {
    $params = @{}
    if ($jenkinsUserName -ne "") {
        $securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $jenkinsUserPassword -AsPlainText -Force 
        $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($jenkinsUserName, $securePwd) 
        $head = @{"Authorization" = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jenkinsUserName + ":" + $jenkinsUserPassword ))}
        $params = @{
            Headers = $head;
            Credential = $credential;
            ContentType = "text/plain";
        }
    }

    # If your Jenkins uses the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" security option (which it should), 
    # when you make a POST request, you have to send a CSRF protection token as an HTTP request header.
    # https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API
    try {
        $tokenUrl = $jenkinsServer + "crumbIssuer/api/json?tree=crumbRequestField,crumb"
        $crumbResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Get @params -UseBasicParsing -SessionVariable session | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host "CSRF protection is enabled, adding CSRF token to request headers"
        $params.Headers += @{$crumbResult.crumbRequestField = $crumbResult.crumb}
    } catch {
        Write-Host $Error[0]
    }

    Write-Host "Start the build"
    $returned = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $jobUrlWithParams -WebSession $session -Method Post -UseBasicParsing @params
    Write-Host "Job URL Link: $($returned.BaseResponse.Headers['Location'])"
    $jobResult = "$($returned.BaseResponse.Headers['Location'])/api/json"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jobResult -Method Get @params -WebSession $session
    $buildUrl = $Response.executable.url
    while ($buildUrl -eq $null -or $buildUrl -eq "") {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jobResult -Method Get @params -WebSession $session
        $buildUrl = $Response.executable.url
    }
    Write-Host "Build Number is: $($Response.executable.number)"
    Write-Host "Job URL Is: $($buildUrl)"
    $buildResult = "$buildUrl/api/json?tree=result,number,building"
        
    $isBuilding = "True"
    $i = 0
    Write-Host "Estimate Job Duration: " $jobTimeout
    while ($isBuilding -eq "True" -and $i -lt $jobTimeout) {       
        $i += 5
        Write-Host "waiting $checkIntervals secs for build to complete"
        Start-Sleep -s $checkIntervals
        $retyJobStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildResult -Method Get @params -WebSession $session

        $isBuilding = $retyJobStatus[0].building
        $result = $retyJobStatus[0].result
        $buildNumber = $retyJobStatus[0].number
        Write-Host "Retry Job Status: " $result " BuildNumber: "  $buildNumber  " IsBuilding: "  $isBuilding 
    }
    if ($failBuild) {
        if ($result -ne "SUCCESS") {
            Write-Host "BUILD FAILURE: build is unsuccessful or status could not be obtained."
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Exception in jenkins job: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```